# Media keys do not work on Amarok

Tags: shortcut-keys, media, amarok

in previous versions of Ubuntu, media keys used to work on my computer to control Amarok. But they don't anymore.

The play/pause button works for Totem.

A have already checked the shortcuts configuration on Amarok and on Ubuntu. Both configurations seem to be OK.

My Ubuntu version: 15.10

My computer: Dell Vostro 1320

Comment: Obs: I'm using Unity.